# Is there any way to view/show card numbers on every card?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

It would be easier to refer to a card using the card number. I see that when you open a card, it shows a number at the bottom right. Is there a way to see this number when the cards are shown on the board. Also, does a similar functionality exits on the Android app ?

Comment: You could manually add the card number to the title of the card, but it doesn't sound like a very convenient thing to do.

Comment: Can you reproduce the results of sirthomas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to display card numbers from the board view. You can suggest this feature at `feature-ideas@trello.com`

A quick workaround for this until there is a solution is to hover over the card title in the board view. The URL preview provided by the browser (e.g. in Chrome the URL preview of the link is at the bottom left of the browser) will show the card's link. The number at the end of this URL corresponds to the number of the card.

Not a great solution, but the only way to see the card number without actually clicking into it.

Comment: 2021 Update! -- Download this chrome extension and boom, DONE - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-prime/mkphpfbogfpojbbmbdhfcboleippkffh?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

There is now a Power-Up in the power ups list that allows you to add card numbers to all cards. Just enable the powerup and you'll see the number on the front and back of all cards.

No browser extension needed, it's provided through the official directory of power-ups and works in the new standalone apps.

Comment: What's the name?

Comment: http://info.trello.com/power-ups/card-numbers You should be able to find it in the power up list

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this bookmarklet](http://razbakov.com/blog/673-show-number-trello-card/).

I'm going to create some Google Chrome Extension in near future.

But this bookmarklet is very simple fast solution to show card numbers on each card.

Answer (score 2):

You can hack your way to adding card numbers for everybody (without requiring everyone to install an extension) by using the third party [Butler for Trello](https://butlerfortrello.com/) tool, which lets you run automated actions on certain triggers.

Since Trello currently does actually have card numbers for each card in its data model (which is exposed via the API), we can get Butler to write the card numbers into the names of each card.

After you [follow the instructions](https://trello.com/c/vqhGFZIU) to add the Butler user to your board, the bot will add a "Butler" list to Trello. Add the following cards to it:

- `when a card not in list "Butler" is added to the board, rename the card to "#{cardnumber} {triggercardname}"`
- `when the name of a card not in list "Butler" with a name starting with "#{* } " is changed, remove the matched text and rename the card to "#{cardnumber} {cardname}"`
- `when the name of a card not in list "Butler" and with a name not starting with "#" is changed, rename the card to "#{cardnumber} {cardname}"`

Now when you edit a card's title, the card's number appears at the start:

[image: screenshot of Butler configured to add card numbers]

**Disclaimer:** I am an Atlassian (which develops Trello) employee, but this is not an official recommendation or advice. This technique may stop working at any time due to either changes in Trello or Butler for Trello (no affiliation). Consider [using card linking](https://trello.com/c/K2tAhCUP/36-you-can-link-cards-together-click-to-find-out-how) to refer to cards instead, which is resilient to e.g. moving a card from one board to another.

Answer (score 1):

Caspar's answer was the key for me. Now that Butler is part of Trello, the steps have changed a bit, but the idea is the same and this solution works for Trello "Free teams" without using up a power-up. It also doesn't require a browser extension.

Here is the rule I'm using:

```
when a card is added to the board by anyone, rename the card to "{cardnumber} {cardname}"
```

[image: screenshot of example Trello Butler Rule]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might get your wish ... card numbers just showed up on my Trello board.  Not sure if it was due to some funky filtering I did, or if they just pushed an update.  Either way, I'm looking for a switch to toggle on/off, otherwise it just adds more clutter in cases where you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Your share however, doesn't fitt the criteria of an answer. Read the [faq] section to figure out why.

Comment: Is there a setting? I cannot see any numbers

Comment: And... they've disappeared again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that's why I created this plugin few days back.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-prime/mkphpfbogfpojbbmbdhfcboleippkffh?hl=en